# Explode the posted data to receive Date in php

Tags: php, datetime, explode

I am forwarding my email coming to my domain to a php script. Its quite big, I don't know why stackoverflow is not allowing me to post full lenth as it gives error `this looks like spam.`

However, Its date part looks something like

```
.......\nFrom: Firstname Lastname <name@gmail.com>\nDate: Sun, 17 Feb 2019 08:09:37 +0545\nMessage-ID: <abcdefghifsfsasd@mail.gmail.com>\nSubject:.......
```

My intention is to get the received datetime of this email.

There I can see `Date: Sun, 17 Feb 2019 08:09:37 +0545`. This date is the required datetime for me. How, can I get it?

I tried exploding with `preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $_POST['headers']);` but then I can't get Idea as it seems series of strings.

```
"Received: by mx0035p1mdw1.sendgrid.net with SMTP id ADiBRHCowl Sun, 17 Feb 2019 02:59:38 +0000 (UTC)",
   "Received: from mail-ed1-f48.google.com (mail-ed1-f48.google.com [209.85.208.48]) by mx0035p1mdw1.sendgrid.net (Postfix) with ESMTPS id DB6E7A05D27 for <email@domain.com>; Sun, 17 Feb 2019 02:59:37 +0000 (UTC)",
   "Received: by mail-ed1-f48.google.com with SMTP id m35so7028682ede.10 for <email@domain.com>; Sat, 16 Feb 2019 18:59:37 -0800 (PST)",
   "DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed\/relaxed; d=gmail.com; s=20161025; h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to; bh=ttLV0Sk78+4DRG2CM0f\/kiWFXPnwCHm0Y\/1zM9lMrRo=; b=Dgyv4S\/TDdo61RsYchmhkFnFtG8VksVIeAimm7WOnHSv6chN+LOG25ufsh4\/51xX1Z pjQvuiXnuR7MawZ0B\/WZxB4F4309XT9SIrZMBX9\/5HHd\/SddFx1LZ6XVS2qEvaVV9B\/9 4v\/wqNhnNr7Vy1GlKbUq6buB9l4fk9J+ralDNF6lrDbP1XVCv+58Qp0UipMLPzYmFGnf EtylH7N4vVNoOjww15MwT5xrgW3ylfSJLZXog3TBxK+v8fGFKQ0UOH\/+C5PL0sQaFVM5 EVGtwQgqbBeEhJnG77xVuApcerYNYY+gM1Sixjb4NhRtsKgE5fOTAzA3N+jXbDIVunsZ F45g==",
   "X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed\/relaxed; d=1e100.net; s=20161025; h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to; bh=ttLV0Sk78+4DRG2CM0f\/kiWFXPnwCHm0Y\/1zM9lMrRo=; b=s\/ovc9XPMypTBh6anKxw1WFQRJ3I4AGVFaQdu9L0buU2m8tl2JFPLWOYeliRS5K\/Jd WLiTXfRdFw8OpAWuKUbMt0wQ+gZXd0AwpJb\/t5KFs+Fh7l0cjWRSK\/0ZzADqagoyDmhC ISSRazoYBu2h9IeWdOhFV4i+VBvyhkXqauggB6kvZxG4GM\/ulB7sj5zYajnVBt5SfSI1 9SHMkkZrYerI6mCAKgqr\/eEj8E0IYgaKlhct9TlZbh9wsmYUQoDzp4Wf9JET5jhL7Lya 3Pa41NZepc03HfGOcnYadrPfrIz7O2Tm++22D0LBTzozkskwlJqqZz\/rLf0Osu81q80h VdEg==",
   "X-Gm-Message-State: AHQUAuaQnQxerRWkc4sbGZmEt9JioFURi6LQDVYBzb60RKG+21LzjDlV OgAylSy0nmPPAEI7A\/Faxook200gMFui+BFD8sWrBg==",
   "X-Google-Smtp-Source: AHgI3IZGrcH6ngLPOL8YS8PuOU6OPlSk2Q2DDeKmX41lGFBsvhtZ2FFtGkGypCSGCeVJd\/wP6i+pi2S6v5EIJaZOxNA=",
   "X-Received: by 2002:aa7:dacd:: with SMTP id x13mr13739830eds.24.1550372376434; Sat, 16 Feb 2019 18:59:36 -0800 (PST)",
   "MIME-Version: 1.0",
   "From: Firstname Lastname <name@gmail.com>",
   "Date: Sun, 17 Feb 2019 08:44:24 +0545",
   "Message-ID: <CACX9xtmKSuZYgnXXEq-z=jtBwG4DG=ytptVVCOsY7SEOi2o_KQ@mail.gmail.com>",
   "Subject: dummy12",
   "To: email@domain.com",
   "Content-Type: multipart\/alternative; boundary=\"000000000000c45c6e05820e32b0\"",
   ""
```

How can I get datetim from this line `"Date: Sun, 17 Feb 2019 08:44:24 +0545"`

**update:**

After preg_split `$res = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $_POST['headers']);`

```
if(count($res)>0){
  $output = $res[10];
}
```

At this point $output is `Date: Sun, 17 Feb 2019 08:09:37 +0545`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, may not be it is best but it is doing the job.

```
$f_header = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $_POST['headers']);
if(count($f_header)>0){
    $output = substr("$f_header[10]",6);
    $date = explode("+",$output);
    $dt = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($date[0]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As email headers are fairly consistent (and always consistent in how the data is formatted), you could use a RegEx pattern to match the date value.

```
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match('/"Date: (.+?)",/', $headers_data, $matches);
```

$matches will be an array containing, if successful, two elements: the total matched substring, and the captured date data.  You'll probably be most interested in the latter, which would be at:

```
$matches[1]
```

Check the PHP manual for more on [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: I received the returnValue as 0. Could you please check the question, I have updated it.

Comment: My post was formatted in a way that probably caused confusion.  You're not checking $returnValue, but rather the $matches array.  If successful, you'll have multiple values in the array.  At position 0 will be the full substring matched.  And at position 1 ought to be the date time captured.

Comment: received an empty array `[]`

Comment: You're replacing $headers_data with $_POST['headers'], right?  Or whatever variable contains your header data.

Comment: `Undefined variable: headers_data in` this will be the error if I tried $headers_data